# Is it safe to send back a faulty hard disk that contains personal data?

Tags: hard-drive, password, security

I bought a hard disk on which I installed Ubuntu. Now there are personal files on the hard disk. Within a month, the disk died and I want to send it back for warranty. There is not so much interesting on there, except some browser passwords. I did not encrypt the hard disk, but I did use a password for my account.

This got me thinking: is it possible that an actor with physical access to the hard drive access any personal files? I'm guessing it is only beholden to file permissions, which are often read for everyone.

Comment: It depends on what "died" means. Boot from a Live USB, and `shred` the disk, just in case. The warranty provider's  behavior could range from "toss it in the recycling bin with the rest" to "Aha! Sending  him the disk that will fail after he loads his data was a good idea! Now we've got him!". OK, that was a little paranoid, but once you send the disk away, it's out of your control.

Comment: File permissions do ***not*** prevent access to data on disk. Only if you had encrypted your files or the whole disk, it would be safe.

Comment: A paranoid person would actually shred the disk, but that is not under the warranty terms.  Changing passwords would be recommended.

Comment: Thanks! Feel free to upgrade the comment to an answer, anyone. (I'm suddenly feeling a lot less secure with my account password.)

Comment: If you boot from a live medium can you access the disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only you will know the value that can be placed on the data stored on the failed HD if a third party were to have access to it.

Hard Disks are not generally expensive these days. Personally, I would tend to the view that [shredding the disk](https://linux.die.net/man/1/shred) if you have access to it from a live USB would be the best option and replace it either with the same marque or maybe upgrade to an SSD. Other than that, [bash it](https://www.veritysystems.com/news-blog/what-is-the-best-way-to-destroy-a-hard-drive/) with a heavy hammer and write it off to experience.